# cross GCC eclipse build error:undefined reference to `SDL_GetTicks'

Tags: c++, gcc, embedded-linux, yocto, eclipse-cdt

I'm trying to use lvgl library following this [tutorial](https://blog.lvgl.io/2018-01-03/linux_fb) (with eclipse IDE and yocto SDK from [here](https://developer-archives.toradex.com/getting-started/module-2-my-first-hello-world-in-c/cc-application-development-with-the-yocto-projectopenembedded)).

I got an error saying `<SDL2/SDL.h> no such a file or directory` which I think I solved manually downloading SDL2 and including it, But Then I got these errors that i dont know what to do about them:

```
in function `lv_tick_get':
/home/apm/eclipse-workspace/LVGLproj/Debug/../src/lvgl/src/hal/lv_hal_tick.c:77: undefined reference to `SDL_GetTicks'
/opt/poky/3.1.21/sysroots/i686-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/9.5.0/real-ld: /home/apm/eclipse-workspace/LVGLproj/Debug/../src/lvgl/src/hal/lv_hal_tick.c:77: undefined reference to `SDL_GetTicks'
/opt/poky/3.1.21/sysroots/i686-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/9.5.0/real-ld: ./src/lv_drivers/sdl/sdl.o: in function `window_update':
/home/apm/eclipse-workspace/LVGLproj/Debug/../src/lv_drivers/sdl/sdl.c:372: undefined reference to `SDL_UpdateTexture'
/opt/poky/3.1.21/sysroots/i686-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/9.5.0/real-ld: /home/apm/eclipse-workspace/LVGLproj/Debug/../src/lv_drivers/sdl/sdl.c:377: undefined reference to `SDL_RenderClear'
/opt/poky/3.1.21/sysroots/i686-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/9.5.0/real-ld: /home/apm/eclipse-workspace/LVGLproj/Debug/../src/lv_drivers/sdl/sdl.c:387: undefined reference to `SDL_RenderCopy'
/opt/poky/3.1.21/sysroots/i686-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/9.5.0/real-ld: /home/apm/eclipse-workspace/LVGLproj/Debug/../src/lv_drivers/sdl/sdl.c:388: undefined reference to `SDL_RenderPresent'
/opt/poky/3.1.21/sysroots/i686-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/9.5.0/real-ld: /home/apm/eclipse-workspace/LVGLproj/Debug/../src/lv_drivers/sdl/sdl.c:380: undefined reference to `SDL_SetRenderDrawColor'
/opt/poky/3.1.21/sysroots/i686-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/9.5.0/real-ld: /home/apm/eclipse-workspace/LVGLproj/Debug/../src/lv_drivers/sdl/sdl.c:383: undefined reference to `SDL_RenderDrawRect'
/opt/poky/3.1.21/sysroots/i686-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/9.5.0/real-ld: ./src/lv_drivers/sdl/sdl.o: in function `sdl_event_handler':
/home/apm/eclipse-workspace/LVGLproj/Debug/../src/lv_drivers/sdl/sdl.c:272: undefined reference to `SDL_PollEvent'
/opt/poky/3.1.21/sysroots/i686-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/9.5.0/real-ld: /home/apm/eclipse-workspace/LVGLproj/Debug/../src/lv_drivers/sdl/sdl.c:272: undefined reference to `SDL_PollEvent'
/opt/poky/3.1.21/sysroots/i686-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/9.5.0/real-ld: ./src/lv_drivers/sdl/sdl.o: in function `monitor_sdl_clean_up':
/home/apm/eclipse-workspace/LVGLproj/Debug/../src/lv_drivers/sdl/sdl.c:326: undefined reference to `SDL_DestroyTexture'
/opt/poky/3.1.21/sysroots/i686-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/9.5.0/real-ld: /home/apm/eclipse-workspace/LVGLproj/Debug/../src/lv_drivers/sdl/sdl.c:327: undefined reference to `SDL_DestroyRenderer'
/opt/poky/3.1.21/sysroots/i686-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/9.5.0/real-ld: /home/apm/eclipse-workspace/LVGLproj/Debug/../src/lv_drivers/sdl/sdl.c:328: undefined reference to `SDL_DestroyWindow'
/opt/poky/3.1.21/sysroots/i686-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/9.5.0/real-ld: /home/apm/eclipse-workspace/LVGLproj/Debug/../src/lv_drivers/sdl/sdl.c:337: undefined reference to `SDL_Quit'
/opt/poky/3.1.21/sysroots/i686-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/9.5.0/real-ld: ./src/lv_drivers/sdl/sdl.o: in function `sdl_init':
/home/apm/eclipse-workspace/LVGLproj/Debug/../src/lv_drivers/sdl/sdl.c:122: undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
/opt/poky/3.1.21/sysroots/i686-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/9.5.0/real-ld: /home/apm/eclipse-workspace/LVGLproj/Debug/../src/lv_drivers/sdl/sdl.c:124: undefined reference to `SDL_SetEventFilter'
/opt/poky/3.1.21/sysroots/i686-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/9.5.0/real-ld: ./src/lv_drivers/sdl/sdl.o: in function `window_create':
/home/apm/eclipse-workspace/LVGLproj/Debug/../src/lv_drivers/sdl/sdl.c:348: undefined reference to `SDL_CreateWindow'
/opt/poky/3.1.21/sysroots/i686-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/9.5.0/real-ld: /home/apm/eclipse-workspace/LVGLproj/Debug/../src/lv_drivers/sdl/sdl.c:352: undefined reference to `SDL_CreateRenderer'
/opt/poky/3.1.21/sysroots/i686-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/9.5.0/real-ld: /home/apm/eclipse-workspace/LVGLproj/Debug/../src/lv_drivers/sdl/sdl.c:353: undefined reference to `SDL_CreateTexture'
/opt/poky/3.1.21/sysroots/i686-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/9.5.0/real-ld: /home/apm/eclipse-workspace/LVGLproj/Debug/../src/lv_drivers/sdl/sdl.c:355: undefined reference to `SDL_SetTextureBlendMode'
/opt/poky/3.1.21/sysroots/i686-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/9.5.0/real-ld: ./src/lv_drivers/sdl/sdl.o: in function `sdl_init':
/home/apm/eclipse-workspace/LVGLproj/Debug/../src/lv_drivers/sdl/sdl.c:135: undefined reference to `SDL_StartTextInput'
/opt/poky/3.1.21/sysroots/i686-pokysdk-linux/usr/libexec/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/9.5.0/real-ld: ./src/lv_drivers/sdl/sdl_common.o: in function `keycode_to_ctrl_key':
/home/apm/eclipse-workspace/LVGLproj/Debug/../src/lv_drivers/sdl/sdl_common.c:229: undefined reference to `SDL_GetModState'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [makefile:191: LVGLproj] Error 1
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

20:17:37 Build Failed. 23 errors, 0 warnings. (took 2m:544ms)
```

I tried solutions which i thought might help but I couldn't fix it.

Is this even the correct way to do this?
what am i supposed to do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to link against SDL2 too, just including its headers is not enough.

Comment: when I do that i get a new error :
real-ld: cannot find -l/home/apm/eclipse-workspace/LVGLproj/ (SDL2 folder is in this path)
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status